# Apache kafka: Failed to acquire lock on file .lock in tmp/kafka-logs

Tags: apache-kafka

According to official [kafka documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart_multibroker) after command `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic my-replicated-topic` server throw error "Failed to acquire lock on file .lock in tmp/kafka-logs". How to fix it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

just delete directory /tmp/kafka-logs and try again

Comment: And to avoid next error do I need to change listeners (like listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093) in  config/server-1.properties ?

Comment: 1. Will there be any data loss if I delete the logs directory?
2. What is the root cause of this problem?

Comment: @LanaNova please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599625/kafka-unable-to-start-kafka-process-can-not-access-file-00000000000000000000/53653488#comment98345918_53653488)

Comment: Thanks, @nishantambastha. We use one zookeeper for multiple kafkas, so this solution won't work for us.

Comment: I suggest a better way without delete the files: 1. netstat -anp|grep -w :9092 2. kill -9 <pid>

Comment: I removed /tmp/kafka-logs directory. Now, it is giving an error Leader_not_available.

Answer (score 15):

Remove the file .lock in /tmp/kafka-logs:

`rm /tmp/kafka-logs/.lock`.

That way you can keep any pre-existing logs.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem. Removed the kafka log files and worked for me.

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/kafka-logs
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem.
First, I removed the `.lock` file

```
#rm /tmp/kafka-logs/.lock #
```

and still I got below error

> ERROR There was an error in one of the threads during logs loading:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /tmp/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-5/00000000000000000000.log
>   (Permission denied) (kafka.log.LogManager) [2018-04-17 13:35:09,088]
>   FATAL [Kafka Server 0], Fatal error during KafkaServer startup.
>   Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /tmp/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-5/00000000000000000000.log
>   (Permission denied) at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)

so, I had to remove the folder

```
# rm /tmp/kafka-logs #
```

and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Remove kafka-logs folder

Use

```
cd /tmp 
rm -r kafka-logs
```