# Kafka broker shut down even though the log dirs are present

Tags: apache-kafka

When I saw this error message:

> ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in /tmp/kafka-logs have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)

The first thought is "well the `/tmp` directory probably got cleared out by the O/S (linux) - so I should update the *kafka* config to point to something permanent.  However the directory *is* present and has *not* been wiped:

```
ll /tmp/kafka-logs/
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user   38 Apr  7 16:56 __consumer_offsets-0
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user   38 Apr  7 16:56 __consumer_offsets-7
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user   38 Apr  7 16:56 __consumer_offsets-42
..
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user   38 Apr  7 16:56 __consumer_offsets-32
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  141 Apr 12 02:49 flights_raw-0
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  178 Apr 12 08:25 air2008-0
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  141 Apr 12 13:38 testtopic-0
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user 1244 Apr 17 22:29 recovery-point-offset-checkpoint
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user    4 Apr 17 22:29 log-start-offset-checkpoint
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user 1248 Apr 17 22:30 replication-offset-checkpoint
```

So then what does this actually mean, why is it happening and what should be done to correct/avoid the error?

Comment: Please provide what rights for `kafka-logs` dir. Please specify what user runs the broker.

Comment: The `/tmp/kafka-logs` is created automatically under/owned by the user running `kafka` which is `ec2-user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168342/kafka-1-0-stops-with-fatal-shutdown-error-logs-directory-failed?rq=1) best answer suggests to delete log dir both for Kafka `/tmp/kafka-logs` and Zookeper `/tmp/zookeeper`.

Probably it's because of Kafka [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7278) which was resolved in August 2018.

Hope this will help.

Comment: My issue with this is then the _data_ is lost.