# Shutdown broker because all log dirs have failed

Tags: apache-kafka

```
[2019-10-29 10:09:36,903] INFO [ReplicaManager broker=0] Broker 0 stopped fetcher for partitions __consumer_offsets-30,__consumer_offsets-8,__consumer_offsets-4,__consumer_offsets-27,__consumer_offsets-7,__consumer_offsets-46,__consumer_offsets-33,__consumer_offsets-23,__consumer_offsets-49,__consumer_offsets-36,__consumer_offsets-42,topic-0,__consumer_offsets-17,__consumer_offsets-48,__consumer_offsets-11,__consumer_offsets-14,__consumer_offsets-20,__consumer_offsets-0,__consumer_offsets-39,__consumer_offsets-45,__consumer_offsets-1,__consumer_offsets-26,__consumer_offsets-29,__consumer_offsets-10 and stopped moving logs for partitions  because they are in the failed log directory C:\tmp\kafka-logs. (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2019-10-29 10:09:36,908] INFO Stopping serving logs in dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2019-10-29 10:09:36,952] ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in C:\tmp\kafka-logs have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

i have started zookeeper,Kafka and producer also. But when i tried to consume data immediately this error is coming in Windows

command: `.\bin\windows\Kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic`

Comment: What happens when you update the `log.dirs` to not use a `/tmp` location?

Comment: Check if this helps [Old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168342/kafka-1-0-stops-with-fatal-shutdown-error-logs-directory-failed)

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue and had to do trial and error. But what I eventually did was to disable the other JRE versions and leave only one enabled. See image attached. This seems to have resolved my problem since my broker doesn't crash anymore.[image: Java Runtime Environment]